# How to get modal present view height

Tags: ios, swift, layout, uikit

For some reason, I have to get the view height of presented modal view height.

First I have a full screen vc, and I can get it view height is 852 for iPhone 14 Pro.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        view.addSubview(openBtn)
        openBtn.center = view.center
        // !-- here is full view bounds is (0.0, 0.0, 393.0, 852.0)
        print("full view bounds is \(view.bounds)")
    }

    lazy var openBtn: UIButton  = {
        let btn = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 100))
        btn.backgroundColor = .clear
        btn.setTitle("Open", for: .normal)
        btn.titleLabel?.font = .systemFont(ofSize: 15)
        btn.setTitleColor(.blue, for: .normal)
        btn.addTarget(self, action: #selector(openBtnAction), for: .touchUpInside)
        return btn
    }()
    
    @objc func openBtnAction() {
        self.present(TestVC(), animated: true)
    }
}
```

When present a modal VC, I get the view height is still 852.0

```
import UIKit

class TestVC: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        view.backgroundColor = .gray
        // !! -- here is modal view bounds is (0.0, 0.0, 393.0, 852.0)
        print("modal view bounds is \(view.bounds)")
    }

}
```

[image]

How can I get the real view height of present modal VC?

Comment: Check the height in `viewDidAppear`, not `viewDidLoad`.

Comment: if you want it in viewdidload cycle you can use it in DispatchQueue.main.async {print("modal view bounds is \(view.bounds)")}

Comment: *"For some reason, I have to get the view height of presented modal view height."* -- Are you sure? If you tell us the *reason*, it's very possible we can explain why you *don't **really*** need to.